# How to administrate this estructure on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, quota

There are multiple companies using one application. So I want to have, or know if this is the best way, to create a project for each company, all this with the Firebase API, to create everything programmatically. But I think this is too difficult to do and get that structure. The truth is that the documentation about the Rest API to create projects is not very clear and I am getting lost. One of the things that I want to structure projects like this is to know how much use is made of each project, calculate requests and use of storage. But I don't know if there are other ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's **not possible** to create a new project for Firebase using the Firebase API, what is possible is to list projects, and create/list apps within an existing project using the [Firebase Management API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/).

For monitoring usage, you can use [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/) to assess the usage of each individual app, per service.